# I get ImportError: No module named ex25 when trying to get python file into shell

Tags: python, python-2.7

On excercise 25 we need to import a python file into the python shell but when i try to import the file it comes up with "ImportError: No module named ex25".

This is the code i am trying to import:

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """Sorts the words."""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
    """Prints the last word after popping it off"""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print words

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_words(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

This is the message i receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import ex25
ImportError: No module named ex25
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is exercise 25?

Comment: are they in the same folder?

Comment: Do you have a module called *ex25*?

Comment: Put the code into a file call ex25.py and save the file in the *same* directory where you are executing the shell.

Comment: @Usernamenotfound Yes, i have saved the shell file and lpthw in the same folder.

Comment: @BillBell Is this the same as saving both the shell and ex25.py in the same folder?

Comment: @CristiFati yes

Comment: @JSimonsen To write out the code that is shown above and try to import it into the python shell to try and run it.

Comment: @HhHhHh: Answer: yes. Can you outline the steps you took before you received that diagnostic message. I want to know what environment you were in and what software you're using. I can guess but want to be sure.

Comment: @BillBell i wrote out the code, saved it to the folder lpthw. I then opened shell, saved as shell in lpthw and typed "import ex25" in the shell.

Comment: Can't help. Have never used that website, can't understand enough of the detail.

Comment: @BillBell ok thanks anyway